# Why does ForkJoinPool::invoke() block the main thread?

Tags: java, java-8, fork-join, forkjoinpool

Disclaimer: It's the first time I'm using Java's Fork-Join framework, so I'm not 100% sure I'm using it correctly. Java is also not my main programming language, so this could also be relevant.

---

Given the following [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;

class ForkCalculator extends RecursiveAction
{
    private final Integer[] delayTasks;

    public ForkCalculator(Integer[] delayTasks)
    {
        this.delayTasks = delayTasks;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute()
    {
        if (this.delayTasks.length == 1) {
            this.computeDirectly();
            return;
        }

        Integer halfway = this.delayTasks.length / 2;

        ForkJoinTask.invokeAll(
            new ForkCalculator(
                Arrays.copyOfRange(this.delayTasks, 0, halfway)
            ),
            new ForkCalculator(
                Arrays.copyOfRange(this.delayTasks, halfway, this.delayTasks.length)
            )
        );
    }

    private void computeDirectly()
    {
        Integer delayTask = this.delayTasks[0];

        try {
            Thread.sleep(delayTask);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            System.exit(2);
        }

        System.out.println("Finished computing task with delay " + delayTask);
    }
}

public final class ForkJoinBlocker
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ForkCalculator calculator = new ForkCalculator(
            new Integer[]{1500, 1400, 1950, 2399, 4670, 880, 5540, 1975, 3010, 4180, 2290, 1940, 510}
        );

        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(
            Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
        );

        pool.invoke(calculator);

        //make it a daemon thread
        Timer timer = new Timer(true);

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    System.out.println(pool.toString());
                }
            },
            100,
            2000
        );
    }
}
```

So I create a `ForkJoinPool` to which I submit some tasks which do some processing. I replaced them with `Thread.sleep()` for the purposes of this example, to keep it simple.

In my actual program, this is a very long list of tasks, so I want to periodically print the current status on the standard-output. I try to do that on a separate thread using a scheduled `TimerTask`.

However, I noticed something that I wasn't expecting: in my example the output is something like:

```
Finished computing task with delay 1500
Finished computing task with delay 2399
Finished computing task with delay 1400
Finished computing task with delay 4180
Finished computing task with delay 1950
Finished computing task with delay 5540
Finished computing task with delay 880
.......
```

Which means the "status-task" is never executed.

However if I modify my code to move the `pool.invoke(calculator);` at the very end, then it works as expected:

```
java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool@59bf63ba[Running, parallelism = 4, size = 4, active = 4, running = 0, steals = 0, tasks = 5, submissions = 0]
Finished computing task with delay 1500
java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool@59bf63ba[Running, parallelism = 4, size = 4, active = 4, running = 0, steals = 0, tasks = 5, submissions = 0]
Finished computing task with delay 2399
Finished computing task with delay 1400
java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool@59bf63ba[Running, parallelism = 4, size = 4, active = 4, running = 0, steals = 0, tasks = 4, submissions = 0]
Finished computing task with delay 4180
Finished computing task with delay 1950
......
```

The only conclusion I can draw is that `ForkJoinPool::invoke()` blocks the main-thread (it only returns AFTER all the tasks in the pool are finished).

I expected the code in the main-thread to continue to be executed, while the tasks in the fork-join-pool are handled **asynchronously**.

My **question** is: does this happen because I used the framework incorrectly? Is there something I have to correct in my code?

I noticed one of `ForkJoinPool`s constructors has a `boolean asyncMode` parameter but, from what I can tell from the implementation, this is just to decide between `FIFO_QUEUE` and `LIFO_QUEUE` execution-modes (not exactly sure what those are):

```
public ForkJoinPool(
    int parallelism,
    ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory factory,
    UncaughtExceptionHandler handler,
    boolean asyncMode
) {
    this(checkParallelism(parallelism),
         checkFactory(factory),
         handler,
         asyncMode ? FIFO_QUEUE : LIFO_QUEUE,
         "ForkJoinPool-" + nextPoolId() + "-worker-");
    checkPermission();
}
```

Comment: Did you read the docs for `invoke`?

Comment: @user695022 I did... any particular hint you are inclining towards?

Comment: Are you saying I should use `execute()` instead? Oracle's own docs about this uses `invoke()` ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html ), which is why I didn't try changing it.

Comment: The first part: "Performs the given task, returning its result upon completion." It says right there it doesn't return until the tasks are complete.

Comment: for someone fairly new to java, this is a very good question.. definitely have my upvote

Comment: you btw could accept this correct answer here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically `invoke()` will wait for the entire task to finish before returning, so yes the main thread is blocking. After that, the `Timer` doesn't have time to execute because it runs on a daemon thread.

You can simply use `execute()` instead of `invoke()` which runs the task asynchronously. Then you can `join()` on the `ForkJoinTask` to wait for the result, during which the `Timer` would be running:

```
ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
pool.execute(calculator);

    //make it a daemon thread
Timer timer = new Timer(true);

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(pool.toString());
        }
    }, 100, 2000);

calculator.join(); // wait for computation
```

Comment: Hmmm. So `invoke();` == `execute(); join();` ? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @RaduMurzea exactly. `externalSubmit(task);return task.join();` last two lines from `invoke`

Comment: you could also use `pool.submit(task)` which returns a `Future<T>` subtype `ForkJoinTask<T>` and you can call `get()` to get the result or block if the task submitted hasn't completed yet.